# Tokens produced by Shingle filter are not included in the query - Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

```
public class CustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH = 255;
    private int maxTokenLength = DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH;

    @Override
    protected Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName,final Reader reader) {
        final ClassicTokenizer src = new ClassicTokenizer(getVersion(), reader);
        src.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
        TokenStream  tok = new ShingleFilter(src,2,3);
        tok = new ClassicFilter(tok);
        tok = new LowerCaseFilter(tok);
    //    tok = new SynonymFilter(tok,SynonymDictionary.getSynonymMap(),true);
        return new Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(src, tok) {
            @Override
            protected void setReader(final Reader reader) throws IOException {
                src.setMaxTokenLength(CustomAnalyzer.this.maxTokenLength);
                super.setReader(reader);
            }
        };
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Directory dir = new NIOFSDirectory(new File("/home/local/test"));
        IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        CustomAnalyzer analyzer1 = new CustomAnalyzer();
        TokenStream ts=new CustomSynonymAnalyzer().tokenStream("n",new StringReader("cup board"));
        ts.reset();
        System.out.println("Tokens are :");
        while (ts.incrementToken()) {
           System.out.print(ts.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class) + ", ");
        }
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("n", analyzer1);
        Query query = null;
        query = parser.parse("cup board");
        System.out.println("\nQuery is");
        System.out.println(query.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm using Lucene 4.10.4. The output of the above code is,

```
Tokens are :
cup, cup board, board 
Query is
n:cup n:board
```

I expect the resulting query to be **n:cup n:board n:cup board**. But tokens formed by [shingle filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_4/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html?is-external=true) are not appended in the query. I get only **n:cup n:board**. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those tokens aren't getting split by the analyzer, they are getting split by QueryParser syntax. They are separate *query clauses*, not separate terms, because clauses are separated by spaces.

Try a phrase query, to see the difference: `parser.parse("\"cup board\"");`

Comment: How can I achieve that using shingle filter? For the query word "hello world java", I need to form the combination of tokens (hello, hello world, hello world java, world java, java ) in the query.